# Making a website compatible with WebView with android

Tags: android, webview

I hope make this website compatible with the webview

http://www.laposte.net/

I hope display it without horizontal scrollbar ( display it a mobile web site)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to check the meta tags that WebKit on iOS and Android look for when deciding how to display content. It may be as simple as just adding this to your site's `<head>`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

You can find out more about the viewport meta tag (and other things you can do to give mobile users a decent web experience) at the [Safari dev center](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/navigation/) and in this helpful [Mozilla developers post](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag).